# qt 5 qml, when Text control texts are trimed, how to replace chars of "..."

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

my code

```json
Text {
    Layout.topMargin: 5
    Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
    Layout.preferredHeight: columnsItem.titleHeight
    font: Style.h4
    wrapMode: Text.Wrap
    maximumLineCount: 2
    elide: Text.ElideRight
    lineHeight: 1.5
    text: BodyViewModelCpp.findMusicPageColumns.getSubitemProperty(
          modelData, "title")
}
```

I want to let left "..." look like the right hand side one.
They are both marked using red rectangle in following screen shot

[image: my screen shot 202211061627]

Comment: What is `left "..."`? Do you want ellipses on the left as well as on the right?

Comment: dot dot dot symbol, left hand side bigger then right hand side in i posted pictrue..  and their vertial  positions are diffrent, left hand side one  is vertical center ,right hand side one is bottom.

Comment: I guess that's due to ideogrammatic script vs. alphabetical - mid-dots and lowdots. [en.wikipedia on ellipses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to replace the Chinese ellipsis with an alternative right? We can use `TextMetrics` to determine the `elidedText` and we can suppress or replace Chinese ellipsis before it is shown in the `Text` component:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
    Frame {
        width: 200
        Text {
            id: itemLabel
            width: parent.width
            property TextMetrics textMetrics: TextMetrics {
                text: "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
                elideWidth: itemLabel.width
                elide: Text.ElideRight
            }
            text: textMetrics.elidedText.replace(/…$/,"...")
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAByXicbU/LTsMwELz7K1ZRD0VCbsUxVwSnIlFUibMbL8m2Tuxut/SBIvE1fBhfQp1AqAVzmvWMZ2epDp4F5jLfUbFWlIz61jfC3m2VejQlwpuCM+7Z1D88Yk9WqhxuptPhaYEHuXBEkM2BBOuZWaJLlO//wTA2orsp0QP7gCzHLvUBhanYgvzyPBHSrRHRmkO2qBA28SpYst838OIPsNrVAS34V2SQs+7M6QjWl9mfEHRk8blvOpzxT9nB27fSd5E/UVlJYmuTqW94cZLuImyXwBicKXA8+Xz/GE2uM611dqXSoFa1X8C/gYw=)

Comment: thanks!   finaly my code :
```json
Text {
id: etb
//...
font: Style.h4
wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
maximumLineCount: 2
elide: Text.ElideRight
text: BodyViewModelCpp.findMusicPageColumns.getSubitemProperty( modelData, "title")
TextMetrics {
    elideWidth: etb.width * etb.lineCount 
    elide: etb.elide
    text: etb.text
    font: etb.font
    onElidedTextChanged: {
 if (!etb.truncated)
     return
 etb.text = (elidedText.replace( /.$/, "...")) //in chinese case, dot dot dot symbol is a wide char
    }
}
}

```